# How to change start directory of an scheduled task with schtasks.exe in Windows programatically?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, taskscheduler

I am trying to schedule a task with this command

```
SCHTASKS /Create  /TN MyTaks  /SC minute /MO 1 /TR "%cd%\myfile.exe"
```

I need Task Scheduler run my file inside current directory of `myfile.exe`.
How this can be done considering that I tested this command also.

```
SCHTASKS /Create  /TN MyTaks  /SC minute /MO 1 /TR "\%cd%"%cd%\myfile.exe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with adding /V1

```
SCHTASKS  /Create /V1 /TN MyTask /SC minute /MO 1 /TR "%cd%\myfile.exe"
```